# Fullcalender Enable a certain date range

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm developing a learner management system, I am using Fullcalendar as a planning tool for classes. A class starts on date A example 2019-09-01 and ends on Date B example 2019-09-30. How do I disable the ability to create/drag events on dates outside this range?

Comment: Look up the "validRange" option in the docs. Or maybe "eventConstraint", and "selectConstraint". Either might suit your purpose. You can read about them. Did you do any research yet? Both the fullCalendar documentation and the previous questions on this site would help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort out the issue, i was using V2, upgraded to V4 and used validRange. Sorted :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var isValidEvent = function (start, end, resource) {
            return $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
                return (event.rendering === "background" && resource.id == event.resourceId &&  //Add more conditions here if you only want to check against certain events
                        (moment(start.format()).isSameOrAfter(event.start)) &&
                        (moment(end.format()).isSameOrBefore(event.end)));
            }).length > 0;
        };
```

Comment: A) a good quality answer includes an explanation of the solution. B) You're assuming fullCalendar V3, but OP never mentioned the version. C) the fullCalendar API includes more efficient ways to achieve this, built in